# Comparing two tables in Sqlite using common column

Tags: android

I'm creating an app which automatically lists the calls and sms of a day in the order of time. I completed the codes to store both sms and calls to the Database using services. I have 2 table:

```
Table Call(number, name, call_type, call_duration, date, time, time_in_milliseconds (long)) 
Table Sms(number, name, message, date, time, time_in_milliseconds (long))
```

I need to compare both tables based on `time_in_milliseconds`, and retrieves the entire row and set to text view in the order of `time_in_milliseconds` increases.

Comment: what exactly do you want to compare? I mean what exactly do you what to select in sqlite query?

Comment: From question, it seems like you want to combine tables and show based on time. For this, Join both tables using CROSS JOIN and then order by time_in_millis

Comment: For Eg: I had a call at 12.30, the details of call will go to cal table. Then I recvd a sms at 12.35, the details will go to sms table.. i want to retrieve the call details first, since it happened first,,then the message details...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly you can use this code:

```
        ourDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT number, name, call_type, call_duration, date, time, time_in_milliseconds " +
            " FROM Call " +
            " UNION " +
            " SELECT number, name, message, date, time, time_in_milliseconds " +
            " FROM Sms " +
            " ORDER BY time_in_milliseconds", null);
```

Comment: for bring newest call and sms to first you can use `desc` end of query.